# How to setup git repository subfolder mirror?

Tags: git, github, laravel

It is known that [Laravel Framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) consist of library collection named Illuminate. In which some libraries are mirrored into separate repositories, right under https://github.com/illuminate/ namespace.

How mirror like this is setup and automated?

Comment: see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Comment: Thanks. Then this question belong here right?

Comment: It is "If you are trying to figure out how to use git to do something, understanding the conceptual foundations of git". I am wondering on how a git mirror like laravel's works (setup and automated). It is either a workflow and/or additional automation tools which I prefer it is in the scope of engineering.